# Brownie - TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'TransactionReceipt'

Tags: solidity, python, error, brownie

I made a simple voting smart contract and got a TypeError when I was testing the function "test_can_endorse_candidate".

Solidity Code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract votingContract is Ownable{

    mapping(string => uint) public candidateToSupporters;
    mapping(string => mapping(address => uint)) public candidateToFunds;
    mapping(string => bool) public candidateToExistence;
    bool public voted = false;
    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeedAddress;
    uint public MINIMUM_DEPOSIT = 10 * (10 ** 18);

    struct Candidate{
        string name;
        uint supporters;
    }

    Candidate[] public candidates;

    constructor(address _priceFeedAddress) public{
        priceFeedAddress = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);
    }
    

    function vote(string memory _name) public onlyOwner{
        alreadyVoted();
        if(candidateToExistence[_name] == false){
            candidates.push(Candidate(_name, 1));
            candidateToSupporters[_name]++;
            candidateToExistence[_name] = true;
        }
        else{
           candidateToSupporters[_name]++;
        }
    }

    function alreadyVoted() public{
        require(voted == false, "You have already voted");
    }


    function getNumCandidates() public view returns (uint){
        return candidates.length;
    }

    function getNumSupporters(string calldata _name) public view returns (uint){
        require(candidateToExistence[_name] == true, "Candidate Doesn't Exist!");
        return candidateToSupporters[_name];
    }

    function getPrice() public returns (uint){
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeedAddress.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer * 10 ** 9);
    }

    function getConversionRate(uint ethAmount) public returns(uint){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUSD = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / (10 ** 18); //both eth price and eth amount have 10^18 on them alredy
        return ethAmountInUSD;

    }

    function endorseCandidate(string calldata _name) public payable{
        require(candidateToExistence[_name] == true, "Candidate Doesn't Exist!");
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= MINIMUM_DEPOSIT);
        candidateToFunds[_name][msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function getDepositedAmount() public returns (uint){ 
        uint price = getPrice();
        uint precision = 1 * 10**18;
        return((MINIMUM_DEPOSIT * precision) / price);
    }
    

    function killContract() public onlyOwner{
        selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    }


}
```

test file:

```
from brownie import votingContract
from scripts.deploy import deploy_voting_contract
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account
from web3 import Web3

def test_can_vote():
    #Arrange
    account = get_account()

    #Act
    voting_contract = deploy_voting_contract()
    #Assert
    assert voting_contract.candidateToExistence("George Washington") == False

    #Act
    voting1 = voting_contract.vote("George Washington", {"from": account})
    voting1.wait(1)
    #Assert
    assert voting_contract.candidateToExistence("George Washington") == True

    #Act
    voting2 = voting_contract.vote("Abraham Lincoln", {"from": account})
    voting2.wait(1)
    #Assert
    assert voting_contract.candidateToExistence("Abraham Lincoln") == True


def test_getNumCandidates():
    #Arrange
    account = get_account()

    #Act
    voting_contract = deploy_voting_contract()
    numCandidates = voting_contract.getNumCandidates()
    #Assert
    assert numCandidates == 0

    #Act
    voting1 = voting_contract.vote("George Washington", {"from": account})
    voting1.wait(1)
    numCandidates = voting_contract.getNumCandidates()
    #Assert
    assert numCandidates == 1

    #Act
    voting2 = voting_contract.vote("Abraham Lincoln", {"from": account})
    voting2.wait(1)
    numCandidates = voting_contract.getNumCandidates()

    #Assert
    assert numCandidates == 2
    

def test_getNumSupporters():
    #Arrange
    account = get_account()

    #Act
    voting_contract = deploy_voting_contract()
    voting1 = voting_contract.vote("George Washington", {"from": account})
    voting1.wait(1)
    supporters = voting_contract.getNumSupporters("George Washington")
    #Assert
    assert supporters == 1

    #Act
    voting2 = voting_contract.vote("George Washington", {"from": account})
    voting2.wait(1)
    supporters = voting_contract.getNumSupporters("George Washington")
    #Assert
    assert supporters == 2

def test_can_endorse_candidate():
    #Arrange
    account = get_account()
    #Act
    voting_contract = deploy_voting_contract()
    voting1 = voting_contract.vote("George Washington", {"from": account})
    voting1.wait(1)
    money = voting_contract.getDepositedAmount()
    endorse_candidate = voting_contract.endorseCandidate("George Washington", {"from": account, "value": money})
    endorse_candidate.wait(1)
    #Assert
    assert voting_contract.candidateToFunds("George Washington")(account.address) == money
```

Error:

```
    def test_can_endorse_candidate():
        #Arrange
        account = get_account()
        #Act
        voting_contract = deploy_voting_contract()
        voting1 = voting_contract.vote("George Washington", {"from": account})
        voting1.wait(1)
        money = voting_contract.getDepositedAmount()
>       endorse_candidate = voting_contract.endorseCandidate("George Washington", {"from": account, "value": money})
E       TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'TransactionReceipt'

tests/test_votingContract.py:81: TypeError
```

Comment: What's the value of `money`?

Comment: It would be the  ((10 * 10^18) * (1 * 10^18)) / (whatever the price in eth is * 10^9)

Comment: Can you print it out the real value? My suspicious it is that something is assigned to it that is not a number.

Comment: I tried to print it out and nothing printed. I think you were right that it was not printing an integer. I changed the value of money to Web3.toWei(1, "ether") to see if it would work, but I got a new error: `ValueError: candidateToFunds Sequence has incorrect length, expected 2 but got 1

tests/test_votingContract.py:85: ValueError`

on this line: `assert voting_contract.candidateToFunds("George Washington")(account.address) == money`

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that `getDepositedAmount` isn't a view function so when called as `money = voting_contract.getDepositedAmount()` it returns a transaction's receipt object.

To fix that you have to change the declaration to `view`

```
function getDepositedAmount() public view returns (uint){ 
    uint price = getPrice();
    uint precision = 1 * 10**18;
    return((MINIMUM_DEPOSIT * precision) / price);
}
```

Similarly with `getPrice()`, this also requires `priceFeedAddress.latestRoundData()` to also be a view function

```
function getPrice() public view returns (uint){
    (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeedAddress.latestRoundData();
    return uint256(answer * 10 ** 9);
}
```

The second issue is that when calling `voting_contract.candidateToFunds` you need to pass the parameters in a single call. Something like this:

```
assert voting_contract.candidateToFunds("George Washington", account.address) == money
```